# Need help to work with characters longer than 2 or more bytes in Python

Tags: python, binary, byte, bit

I'm learning about bits and bytes in python by writing a small program that converts strings to binary and back to string again. Temporarily I only have a function that converts to binary.

```
string = 'word'

for c in word:
    convertToBinary(c) #Function that converts to binary
```

Output:

```
01110111
01101111
01110010
01100100
```

Now I want to write a `fromBinary()` function that convert from binary to string. However I'm stuck on how to deal with characters that are longer than 1 byte, like for instance `'å'`.

```
string = 'å'

    for c in word:
        convertToCBinary(c)
```

Output:

```
    11000011
    10100101
```

This becomes a problem when I have a string including characters of different length (in bytes).

string = 'åw'

```
    for c in word:
        convertToCBinary(c)
```

Output:

```
11000011    #first byte of 'å'
10100101    #second byte of 'å'
01110111    #w
```

I was thinking that I could join the bytes back together as one, however I'm really puzzled on how to determine which bytes to join. How can I make a function that recognizes which bytes that together form a character?

Comment: In two words - that's why unicode is hard. I believe [UTF-8 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) in wikipedia might provide some insight (especially "Description") section. Since you're doing this for education purposes it is totally fine to try to do that, but in real code you should have used builtin codecs (code samples in [Python unicode docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) are helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard. Of course there's a system to it - else no program could print or edit names like Ñáñez...

The upper bits in each byte indicate what is the status of that byte:

1) if bit 7 is 0, then it's just ASCII   (`*0*1110111 = w`)

2) if you find a 11 at the top, the that means more byte(s) follow (and how many):

```
   *110*xxxxx *10*xxxxxx
   *1110*xxxx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx
   *11110*xxx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx
   *111110*xx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx
   *1111110*x *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx *10*xxxxxx

11000011    #first byte of 'å'
10100101    #second byte of 'å'
```

Thus:

```
*110* means 1 byte follows:
*110*00011 *10*100101

00011 + 100101 = 000 11100101 = the unicode value for å (0x00e5)
```

Note: I believe there's a problem with your w in your example.

Comment: The w is definitely wrong, I must have made an error when pasting. Going to update it.